# MSSQL JSON_VALUE to match ANY Object in Array

Tags: sql-server, json

I have a table with a JSON text field:

```
create table breaches(breach_id int, detail text);
insert into breaches values
( 1,'[{"breachedState": null}, 
      {"breachedState": "PROCESS_APPLICATION",}]')
```

I'm trying to use MSSQL's in build JSON parsing functions to test whether ANY object in a JSON array has a matching member value.

If the `detail` field was a single JSON object, I could use:

```
select * from breaches 
 where JSON_VALUE(detail,'$.breachedState') = 'PROCESS_APPLICATION'
```

but it's an Array, and I want to know if ANY Object has `breachedState = 'PROCESS_APPLICATION'`

Is this possible using MSSQL's JSON functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function OPENJSON to check each object, try this query:

```
select * from breaches 
where exists
(
    select * 
    from
    OPENJSON (detail) d
    where JSON_VALUE(value,'$.breachedState') = 'PROCESS_APPLICATION'
)
```

Btw, there is an extra "," in your insert query, it should be:

```
insert into breaches values
( 1,'[{"breachedState": null}, 
      {"breachedState": "PROCESS_APPLICATION"}]')
```